# st_buffer throws error when setting SRID

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geo

mysql version: 5.7.10
I can set srid on a lineString as:

```
 SET @line = ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(45.076287 37.5341466,
  45.0763506 37.5339578, 45.0763677 37.5338354, 45.0764356 37.5328037,
  45.0764417 37.5325764, 45.0764387 37.5325154, 45.0764378 37.5320371,   
  45.0764671 37.5313518, 45.0764922 37.530762, 45.0764985 37.5306131, 
45.0765163 37.5304027, 45.0765576 37.5299127, 45.076546 37.5296679, 
45.0765001 37.5293058, 45.0764386 37.529033, 45.076358 37.5288548, 
45.0761693 37.5285545, 45.0758591 37.5280275, 45.0754983 37.5274145, 
45.0750665 37.5266809, 45.0750011 37.5265698, 45.07488 37.5263839, 
45.0746177 37.5260407, 45.0713792 37.5222661, 45.0712138 37.5220454, 
45.0710956 37.5218053, 45.0708632 37.5211612, 45.0706554 
37.5207316)',4326);
```

But when I try to convert my lineString into a polygon it gives me error: 
`Incorrect arguments to st_buffer`
My str_buffer:

```
SET @buffer=st_buffer(@line,10)
```

What I'm trying to do is to find points within 10 meters of a line.

Comment: I found that line srid is 1 and srid of the point I create is 0. I don't know exactly what is srid but gues that should be the problem

Comment: if I specify SRID it gives me error, but without indicating SRID it gives the wrong answer.

Comment: That's because I figured out that mysql geo functions only support platter coordinate so my case doesn't apply to this. In other words mysql geo functions can't solve my problem